# Android Git: Making one project and doing changes

Tags: android, eclipse, git

I am working on an android project that have later to be translated to many other languages and some changes have to do in design.

Now I want to know is there any way to make one project and keep it on git and later having changes should change the git project accordingly. So is it possible to create multiple apps for Android project. If yes, is it possible with Eclipse and git or someone has any other idea?

For the time being I am saving project in local directory and copy that project to make changes for next app.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds that you should give git-subtrees a try. There, you create one repo with your base project and then import this repo into your specific app project. If you want to propagate your changes to the API, you push the changes to the base repo. We use this for component development.

But from my experience: do not use eclipse for working with git. It has some major drawbacks and might corrupt the repos. Use the CLI or another tool.